# Vertical line guide at 80 characters for Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Is it possible to turn on a vertical line guide at 80 characters in Bitbucket?

For the pull request, diff and source views for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible to do that. However, the official public issue tracker for Bitbucket itself is **[here](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues?status=new&status=open)**. You can submit a feature request by clicking "Create issue" in the top right of that page.